# Do all capacitors in a DC circuit reach steady state if so then why?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I want to know if capacitors connected in DC circuits having any combination of capacitors and resistors ever reach a steady state(no current flows through the capacitor) If that is the case then how can we prove it for the general case ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not a DC circuit if there are capacitors present. I assume you mean that you have a circuit with DC (constant) sources, resistors, and capacitors only? And your question is essentially "how to prove that all such (ideal) circuits have a DC steady state solution?" The distinction I'm making here is that DC steady state is (mathematically) never reached in finite time (unless the circuit has always been in steady state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on what you mean by a DC circuit. If it involves e.g. a DC voltage source that is instantaneously connected to an LC combination of an inductor and a capacitor with zero-resistance wires, then no, a steady DC state is never reached -- but presumably that's not what you meant.

If, instead, you have a graph of capacitors and resistors (with at least one nonzero resistor) connected as a network to a voltage source (but not a current source, as Alfred Centauri's answer points out) which is instantaneously switched on, then you can use the Thévenin theorem to transform the circuit into a source-resistor simple circuit, where now the resistance of each capacitor is replaced by imaginary reactance, and the resistance of the full circuit then takes on the value of a complex-valued reactance. By examining the different ways that reactances can be combined in each step, it is possible to show that the reactance of the full circuit has positive real part and a definite sign for its imaginary part (depending on what $i$ sign convention you're using).

The system can then be analyzed using a Laplace transform, which will show that all the non-DC components are exponential transients, and will give you the decay time of those exponentials as the $1/RC$ time of the global reactance.

Comment: Re, "...exponential transients..." which, _in theory_, never reach zero, but which , in practice, may quickly become indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: Yes, formally, $e^x\neq 0$ $\forall x$. And if the *rest* of your experiment is accurate enough that it conforms to the mathematical model with an accuracy better than $e^{-1000}$, then you'll be able to detect exponential transients $e^{-t/\tau}$ way up to times $t=1000\tau$. But in the real world, if waiting is not a problem (i.e. unless you're specifically interested in transient phenomena), there's always more interesting places to improve your description of the system.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: Can you specify if and why all RC circuits eventually reach steady state? I don't know enough to understand some of the stuff in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples of circuits consisting of DC (constant) sources, resistors and capacitors that do no have a DC steady state solution. A simple example (with ideal circuit elements) is a series RC circuit driven by a (non-zero) constant current source. The capacitor current is then constant.

Comment: The voltage of your constant current source would increase linearly (forever).

Comment: @R.W.Bird, that's correct, this (ideal) circuit has no DC steady state solution. It is, nonetheless a *valid* ideal circuit (in that it represents a valid differential equation). The dual is the parallel RL circuit connected to a constant voltage source. It too has no DC steady state solution.